# How to keep menu always on top right corner actionbar

Tags: android, menu, show

I have been developing application Android, I have menu items. But my problem, when I was testing on Samsung Galaxy S4, it is not on the top right corner, but if I was testing with Experia (dimension more shorter than Samsung), it can show on top right corner. How to handle it ? only show first item "Pencarian" with icon, but others doesnt show up.

my menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menusearch"
          android:icon="@drawable/searchicon"
          android:title="Pencarian"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"/>    
    <item android:id="@+id/menuadvancedsearch"
          android:icon="@drawable/searchicon2"
          android:title="Pencarian Advanced"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/> <!-- pilihan default collpasactionview -->
    <item android:id="@+id/menulogin"
          android:icon="@drawable/usericon"
          android:title="Login"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
</menu>
```

my code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tab_sport, menu);
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);        

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menusearch:
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                View view = item.getActionView();
                final EditText edtsearchitem=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtsearchitem);
                edtsearchitem.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                            // Perform action on key press                                                      
                            //Global.MainActivity.finish();
                            OtherClass.setKeyword(edtsearchitem.getText().toString());
                            OtherClass.setFlagSearch(true);

                            Intent MyIntentDetailItem=new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchActivity.class);                           
                            startActivity(MyIntentDetailItem);  

                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                ImageView imgcross=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgcross);
                imgcross.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        edtsearchitem.setText("");
                    }
                });

                return true;
            case R.id.menuadvancedsearch:
                OtherClass.setFlagSearch(false);

                Intent MyIntentDetailItem=new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchActivity.class);                           
                startActivity(MyIntentDetailItem);              
                return true;
            case R.id.menulogin:
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                final View inputdialogcustom = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_user, null);
                final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alert.setView(inputdialogcustom);

                final EditText edtuser=(EditText)inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.edtuser);
                final EditText edtpassword=(EditText)inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
                Button btnlogin=(Button)inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
                Button btncancel=(Button)inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

                btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        connection = new ViewConnection(getBaseContext());
                        if (connection.isConnectingToInternet())
                        {
                            BaseUrl=OtherClass.URLlogin+"?user="+edtuser.getText().toString()+
                                    "&pass="+edtpassword.getText().toString();
                            executeAsyncTask();
                        }else {

                            // Internet connection is not present
                            /*LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                            final View inputdialogcustom = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_confirm_connection, null);              
                            AlertDialog.Builder alerterror = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);                                                
                            alerterror.setView(inputdialogcustom);      

                            alerterror.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            }); 
                            alerterror.show();*/
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tidak ada koneksi internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                btncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alert.show();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You cannot do that. The position of the menu is device specific. Most Samsung devices have a physical menu button instead of the overflow menu in the top right.

Comment: Hii Xaver, but I was testing on Samsung tablet Galaxy Tab 2, it shows on the top corner right

Comment: Yes because it doesn't have a physical menu button. Such a button replaces the overflow menu.

Comment: so, I should change to Icon which always on actionbar to replace using of overflow menu, right ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but as I have been trying to tell you, you cannot do anything about that. Where the menu is is a device feature you as a developer cannot change that. And you shouldn't.

Comment: i mean say Goodbye to the Menu Button, and change to icon menu item, like this URL : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: Is your problem solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, or at least you shouldn't. The position of the menu is device specific. Most Samsung devices don't have the overflow menu in the top right but instead have a physical menu button at the bottom. These buttons have been deprecated since Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) but some OEMs still choose to use them. On devices with such a physical menu button the `ActionBar` defaults back to the pre-Honeycomb behaviour and does not display a overflow menu.

---

> **So to summarise:**
>
> The position of the menu button is a device feature. You as a
>   developer have no influence over that. You just define your menu items,
>   but the device decides if they are displayed in a overflow menu or
>   not.

Comment: so I used this link http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html, to solve my problem ?

Comment: Why? What exactly is your problem? I am telling you you don't have one. The position of the menu buttons should be of no concern to you. It's a device specific feature which you have no control over.